# How can I customize FCKeditor with my own buttons?

Tags: asp.net, customization, fckeditor

I need to modify the open-source FCKeditor (not CKeditor) to allow users to select multiple files and upload them in one go (as opposed to selecting them one at a time).

I've found a way to provide the functionality - there are ready made components that can be used.

But how do I add custom buttons with custom functionality in FCKeditor. Anyone know?

Thanks a bunch.

[Revised question]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multiple uploads"?

Comment: Hi Pekka. FCKeditor already has a provision for the user to upload files to the server. But they have to select one file at a time. They want to select multiple files at a time.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a limitation of the browser. You *might* be able to accomplish this with Flash or Silverlight. There are several "multi-file" uploaders out there, but they all require you to select 1 file at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. I added a generic handler. It did not interfere with the working of the control.